# Getting right value from an array within a class that behaves like matrix

Tags: c++

I've got class, that behaves lika a matrix, and all operations there like `+` , `-`, `*` etc work well.. But when I'm trying to get a single value, then I get weird values like 2.08252e-317 ...
I've realized, that this bug happens only, when I want to create new metrix this way:

`const Matrix b = a ;`

without `const` it works well...

this is the declaration of my class:

```
class Matrix {
public:

Matrix(int x, int y);
~Matrix(void);
Matrix operator+(const Matrix &matrix) const;
Matrix operator-() const; 
Matrix operator-(const Matrix &matrix) const; 
Matrix operator*(const double x) const; 
Matrix operator*(const Matrix &matrix) const;

class Proxy {
    Matrix* _a;
    const Matrix* _constA;
    int _i;
public:

  Proxy(Matrix& a, int i) : _a(&a), _i(i) {
    }

    Proxy(const Matrix& constA, int i) : _constA(&constA), _i(i) {
    }

    double& operator[](int j) {
        return _a->_arrayofarrays[_i][j];
    }
};

Proxy operator[](int i) {
    return Proxy(*this, i);
}

Proxy operator[](int i) const {
    return Proxy(*this, i);
}



// copy constructor

Matrix(const Matrix& other) : _arrayofarrays() {
    _arrayofarrays = new double*[other.x ];
    for (int i = 0; i != other.x; i++)
        _arrayofarrays[i] = new double[other.y];

    for (int i = 0; i != other.x; i++)

        for (int j = 0; j != other.y; j++)
            _arrayofarrays[i][j] = other._arrayofarrays[i][j];

    x = other.x;
    y = other.y;
}
int x, y;
double** _arrayofarrays;
};

 //constructor

 Matrix::Matrix(int x, int y) {
_arrayofarrays = new double*[x];
for (int i = 0; i < x; ++i)
    _arrayofarrays[i] = new double[y];
this->x = x;
this->y = y;
}
```

So I create some instance, fill it with values and then, when I want to print value on some index i get those weird values :-/

ie:

```
Matrix a(3,5);
//fill in the values to a
cout << a[1][1] << endl // prints out some nonsence
```

Does anybody have any idea, how to rewrite this class to be able to get proper values?

Comment: Where is the conveniently omitted definition of `Matrix(int x, int y)` ? Furthermore, your operator dereferences `_a` when you clearly have (and potentially are using) the `Proxy(const Matrix&`, int i) construction of `Proxy`. Perhaps check which one is valid, which is not, and add *both* to all constructor initializer lists to ensure whichever is NOT valid is NULL.

Comment: @WhozCraig You mean the constructor? I'll edit it to my post..

Comment: Great, then read the rest of that comment.

Comment: Also, this could easily be simplified as a contiguous matrix (i.e. you do not need a pointer-to-pointer solution). Simple pointer math and a single allocation of `n*m` elements will suffice, with each proxy being handed a row width and base address within the larger matrix where it resides. It is *column* isolation that is eventually going to bite you regardless of which method you use down this current road, but you're likely a ways off form discovering that.

Comment: Hmm now I've realized, thet it works well, when I'm using only `Matrix a (int x, int y);` creation of a new instance...nevertheless I must be also able to create it this way: `const Matrix b=a;` and then when I try to read from b, it fails... How is it possible, that it works for normal matrix and not for `const` ?

Comment: See my prior comment. A const matrix initialized Proxy still tries to use the non-const member `_a` to reference the matrix data, which is never set at construction. [See it live here](http://ideone.com/YuRdFq). The linked sample also reduces the pointer-to-pointer array down to a single block load. Honestly this should be done with smart pointers.